# ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid...

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is
> invalid. The IPA format requires a
> top-level directory named Payload,
> containing only a .app bundle and
> optional plugins in a Plugins
> directory."

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что я не так делаю при добавлении приложения в itunes connect через apllication loader, который и выдает мне эту ошибку?

Сертификаты и профайлы настроены, делаю cmd+B, в products появляется 2 файла, myApp.app и myApp.dSYM.
Я делаю из них архив .zip и пытаюсь его загрузить через application loader, и вовремя `"Veryfying assets with iTunes store"` выдает ошибку, что вверху. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы даете. В стор посылать вообще-то надо из Xcode через Product->Archive , как заархивируется выведется окно органайзера с описание что вы уже архивировали для этого проекта и там же будут кнопки validate - export - submit, submit и шлет в стор. Через export - export for AppStore тоже можно с последующей заливкой.

Можно и самому составить ипа (зип архив) с нужной структурой, какая она конкретно точно не помню, но само приложение валяется в папке Payload (о чем вам и сообщили)

Comment: Спасибо большое, выкладываю 1 раз, а в гугле по 1 ошибке ничего не нашел толком. =(